# How to return position instead of None in this code (Binary Search)

Tags: python

I am trying to return the position in binary search using return mid , if key equals to `lst[mid]`, but it is giving None instead. I am able to print mid:

```
def binary_search(lst,l,r,key):
    print (lst[l:r])
    mid = (l + r) // 2

    if key == lst[mid]:
        print([lst[mid]])
        #print(mid)
        return mid

    elif key > lst[mid]:
        l = mid + 1
        binary_search(lst,l,r,key)

    else:
        r = len(lst[:mid])
        binary_search(lst,l,r,key)


list = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]

print(binary_search(list, 0, len(list), 14 ))
```

Answer (score 5):

When you recursively call `binary_search` you need to return the result. For example:

```
def binary_search(lst,l,r,key):
    print (lst[l:r])
    mid = (l + r )//2

    if key == lst[mid]:
        print ([lst[mid]])
        #print (mid)
        return mid

    elif key > lst[mid]:
        l = mid + 1
        return binary_search(lst,l,r,key) # return me

    else:
        r = len(lst[:mid])
        return binary_search(lst,l,r,key) # and me
```